# How to get specific data using http request?

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest

So I'm really new in android, and going to make an application which get the device id of a device, store it on database server, and then check it if the device are the same with the one already registered, if yes, then go to main activity, if not then they need to registered again. 
My method :

```
public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context context;
    public SigninActivity(Context context, int flag) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(String result) {
    }

    //@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            String dev = (String) arg0[0];
            String link = "http://10.20.2.14/service_antrian/get_data.php?device_id=" + dev;

            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            in.close();
            Log.d("RETURN", "return");
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("EXCEPTION", "EXP");
            //return "failed";
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            UserActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        } else {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            UserActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my service in php code:

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 require_once 'database.php';

 if(isset($_GET['device_id'])) {

     $device_id = $_GET['device_id'];

  $sql = " SELECT * FROM `pasien`.`antrian_mobile` WHERE `device_id`= 
'$device_id' ";

 $rs = $mysqli->query($sql);

$data = array();
while ($row = $rs->fetch_object()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
   if ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0) {
   echo "successfull";
   } else {
       echo "false";
   }

echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

but that code only make the app go to the main activity, while there are no records on the database yet. Is it because of my service?

Comment: Maybe you need to do step down debugging to see where the wrong jump happens. By checking the state of relevant variables, you should be able to find out the missing point

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `successfull` or `failed` from your service

```
if ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0) {
   echo "successfull";
   } else {
       echo "failed";
   }
```

but you are comparing the result with `false` in your mobile app, hence it always takes the else route and open MainActivity

```
if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                UserActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
} else {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                UserActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Comment: editted, sorry. but I changed that earlier and still got the same result

Comment: no worries, could u log the result string and see what's the value? add this 
Log.d("RETURN", result); before this if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))

Comment: it says D/RESULT: Exception: length=0; index=0

Comment: alright, u need to troubleshoot one by one, we check the service first. you log the service link with Log.d("service",link) below String link = "http://10.20.2.14/service_antrian/get_data.php?device_id=" + dev; After u have the value, copy and paste it into browser and see what value your service return. You have to be sure your service is working correctly first.

Comment: I cant log the service link, it straight show this log Log.d("EXCEPTION", "EXP");

Comment: it looks like u have problem with this statement String dev = (String) arg0[0]; Please check what u have passed in. It's better u run debug mode and step over each step to see where the error occurs.

Comment: oh sorry yes I forgot to put the parameter when I call the method, so this is how I call the method new SigninActivity(this, 0).execute(getDeviceID()); , and I checked the link on the log, it says false[].

Comment: the [] at the end of 'false[]' is because of this statement echo json_encode($data); in your service. remove it and try again.

Comment: yes thank you so much it does work now, I thought the  [] was null. thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues in your code:

**issue #1**

`Activity` shouldn't extend `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` should be dedicated to a single asynchronous task (like sending HTTP request) and `Activity` is representing single user screen (UI layer). You should create `AsyncTask` separately and call it within an Activity like this:

```
class SigninActivity extends Activity {

  // this method should be called in the place where you want to execute your task
  // it could be onResume() method, onClick listener for the button or whatever
  private void executeAsyncTask() {
     new MyTask().execute(...) // put your params here...
  }

  private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ... // your task code goes here...
  }
}
```

**issue #2**

Nowadays, using `AsyncTask` is considered as a bad practice in Android applications, because it has poor error handling and is not aware of the Activity lifecycle. Recommended solution for asynchronous operations on Android is RxJava (version 2).

**issue #3**

You are using `HttpClient`. It's recommended to use more mature solutions like Retrofit Http REST client or OkHttp library. They can be easily integrated with RxJava.

**issue #4**

You're passing `Context`, but you're not using it

**issue #5**

You don't have to comment `@Override` annotations.

**issue #6**

Your code is messy, hard to debug and read. Once you make it clean, it will be easier to solve problems related to it.

**issue #7**

In the PHP code, you're mixing responsibilities.

**Summary**

Make sure you're using the existing code correctly and then try to improve it.

Comment: yes thank you I'm really new to this, I'll try to make it better. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @detadet Great!